# Wrong page numbering in thesis

Tags: page-numbering

In a thesis report, I am writing, the Introduction appears immediately after the Table of Contents. I don't want the tOC to have page numbering but want Arabic numbering to start from the introduction and want the same to appear in toc. However, I am not getting the desired output. The page numbering keep getting started from the last page of toc(which is numbered 1) and the first page of Introduction is numbered 2.

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\makeatletter
% these two slashes-commands for continuous chapter numbering in parts of the document
\makeatother
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge}{\thechapter.}{20pt}{\huge\bf} %for chapter headings
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz-cd} % and in the above line to use commutative diagrams
\usepackage[toc,titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{blindtext}
% above three lines for appenices text to appear in Contents
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage[toc]{appendix} % to make appendi appear in the table of contents


 \usepackage{bm} % to use bold font in math mode use \bm{ insert math mode text}


 \allowdisplaybreaks
 \usepackage{tikz-cd} % to draw commutative diagrams




 theoremstyle plain in the text
 \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter] 




\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{color}
\begin{document} 
\begin{titlepage}
   Some text

\end{titlepage}




\pagenumbering{gobble}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction} %to make introduction appear in toc

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\chapter*{Introduction}
Introduction goes here...
\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot whoever helps!

Comment: Your MWE doesn't compile for me, since it makes use of external files. Could you try to remove the mentions to external files (and unneeded packages & declarations)?

Comment: @ABlueChameleon: Please see the edited post. I cleaned it up a bit.

Comment: I'm still unsure what you want though; do you want the ToC page to be unnumbered, then on the next page start the introduction with page number 1, and show that page number in the ToC?

Comment: What are you expecting `\setcounter{page}{1}` to do?  It makes that page 1, and then `\chapter` goes to the next page, which must be 2.

Comment: @ABlueChameleon: I want exactly that.

Comment: @Teepeemm: I compiled after removing the set counter, and I am still getting the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `\pagenumbering` (re)sets the page number to 1, so you don't need `\setcounter{page}{1}`.

The ingredient you are missing is to put `\clearpage` after the T.O.C. so the page numbering can't apply to the last page of the T.O.C.  In summary:

```
...
\tableofcontents
\clearpage % or \newpage, since there are no floats
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter*{Introduction}
...
```

P.S. I remember that `\pagestyle{gobble}` trick!

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is only a shift of one page, then replace `\setcounter{page}{1}` by `\setcounter{page}{0}`.